# Convert NSString to NSDate, adding time

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an NSString that is 05/08/2014.  I want to convert that to an NSDate.  However, I also need to add in time, so that the resulting NSDate looks like this:

```
Thu, 8 May 2014 00:00:00 -0500
```

The time is not important, I just need it to show midnight at the designated timezone.

I have tried:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"];
        NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:textdate.text];
        [dateFormatter release];
        NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
```

But the date comes back as (null).

Comment: The format you set for your dateformatter doesn't match the format of the date you tell it to parse.

Comment: @Logan So, what would be a good way to take the string of 05/08/2014 and convert it to the format for the NSDateFormatter?

Comment: "MM/dd/y" - (more characters for post limit)

Comment: The date format needs to roughly match the format of the date string.  If you want it converted back to a string roughly matching that second example you need to use a *different* date format to go the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is wrong for the first conversion. What you need is first to convert from string to date from one format and form the new date into the new string format. Something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter  *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"]; //convert the string into date (american time zone)
    NSDate *theDate = [formatter dateFromString:textdate.text];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ"];// as @Logan suggested
    NSString *newDate = [formatter stringFromDate:theDate];
```

Comment: Should be "MM/dd/yyyy" he's using american date style.

Comment: Made some edits to the code you posted and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ

Your time zone code was lowercase instead of uppercase.

zzz corresponds to PDT

ZZZ corresponds to -0500

[UTS 35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: I agree, it reads, or writes, a date in `Thu, 8 May 2014 00:00:00 -0500` format.